# How to call another .bat file while current .bat file is running

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wants to run sonar on my project so i'm creating  **.bat**  file for that

//First Step

> I needs to start the server first from this location
>   'C:\Sonar\sonarqube-4.1.1\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat' and after
>   server is online and running...

//Second Step

> Open another cmd and set my project path and execute
>   'C:\Sonar\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.3\bin\sonar-runner.bat' on my
>   project

//What i have done uptil now is first started the server as said in First Step and now i'm executing '.bat' created by me as below

```
@echo off
cd /d D:\PROJECT_Workspace\GUI
call C:\Sonar\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.3\bin\sonar-runner.bat
```

> I wants to merge Two steps as explained above and create one '.bat' which im failing to create.

As im new in creating bat and trying to create bat file so any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @echo off
    cd /d D:\PROJECT_Workspace\GUI
    call C:\Sonar\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.3\bin\sonar-runner.bat
```

...why you do cd in a other folder on D:\ and then run the Sonar-runner.bat from C:\? So the cd line is unnecessary. With the call command you start a second batch and after this you turn back to your first. Try something like:

```
start "" "C:\Batch.bat"
```

The start command opens a new Windows and dont interrupts the first one. You also can use start /wait to have same functionallity like call (The first batch only runs again, when the second batch is finished / closed) . So if both have to run to the same time use start without the wait option.

Comment: i needs to run 'sonar-runner.bat'  file in my workspace directory

Comment: so i needs to switch path n execute the sonar-runner.bat file

Comment: jump in the sonar-runner.bat at the beginning of the batch in the directory. so the line is fine - but write it down in the sonar-runner at start.

Comment: in cmd  D:\PROJECT_Workspace\GUI>C:\Sonar\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.3\bin\sonar-runner.bat

Comment: write "cd /d D:\PROJECT_Workspace\GUI" in the batch "sonar-runner.bat" at first or second line.

Comment: btw the usage of quotation marks for paths would be nice. dont forget, if there is a blank in the path windows thinks the path ends and a option or argument is following -> exception

Comment: but still i cant combined two process (Steps) in one bat file as i said above..is there any way?

Comment: can you send me the code of both scripts ?
you have to ensure that startsonar.bat has finished his processes and then the processes of the second starts. srly it is possible, but hard to say how without code.

Comment: after start of the StartSonar.bat i needs to run the sonar-runner‌​.bat while StartSonar.bat will be in continuous running mode because its a like server...

Comment: this was no code but its helps a bit. so are there repeats / loops in the startsonar.bat or is there a point where is waits and waits until it gets closed to exit the server?

Comment: sonar-runner‌​.bat and StartSonar.bat is not created by me it comes with sonarqube software

Comment: why dont answer the questions ?  you can add the line start "" "C:\Batch.bat" i given u in the anser at the last possition in the startsonor.bat.  this dont interrupts the server and opens a second instance. if there are no big loops so that the startsonar.bat dosnt can reach the line you add, it must works. feel free to vote up if it helps you. if you need more help you have to post the source code of the batches - but i think this should work fine

Comment: startsonar.bat will be running continuously like tomcat server because of this i can access http://localhost:9000/

Answer (score 0):

Just merge those lines into single file, So it will be executed one by one

Create bat file **Sonar.bat** and have below commands

```
@echo off 
call C:\Sonar\sonarqube-4.1.1\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
echo sonar started successfully
cd D:\PROJECT_Workspace\GUI
call C:\Sonar\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.3\bin\sonar-runner.bat
echo sonar test is running ...
```

Create another bat file **RunSonarAndLog.bat** in the same directory of sonar.bat

```
@echo off
echo %DATE% >> Sonar.log
call Sonar.bat >> Sonar.log
echo %DATE% >> Sonar.log
echo press any key to close
pause >nul >> Sonar.log
```

Now you can use the RunSonarAndLog.bat for execution and log the verbos.
If u want to pin your bat file in your windows taskbar for frequent access, pls follow this link - [pin-batfile-in-windows7-taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/100249/how-to-pin-either-a-shortcut-or-a-batch-file-to-the-new-windows-7-8-and-10-task)

*I am wondering why you are changing the directory to workspace ?*

Comment: getting error as                                                                                  ERROR: Sonar server 'http://localhost:9000' can not be reached
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: i needs to run 'sonar-runner.bat'  file in my workspace directory

Comment: i dont think this is the best solution cause the StartSonar.bat may take a while and then the batch overwhelmed themselve.

Comment: yes it will take some time ... cause you should run your test once after the sonar is up right? so it should be sequential not parallel isn't it ? If things should happen in parallel .. yes calling one by one is not opt to ur scenario .. bcs 2nd one will wait until 1st one completes ..

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `call` command to call the files! Like so:

```
echo off
goto :menu
cls
```

:menu
   cls
   echo Type 1 to start initialization & test...
   echo Type 2 to view initialization logs & test logs...
   echo[
   set/p ch= Enter input:
   if %ch% equ 1 goto :initialize
   if %ch% equ 2 goto :logs

```
:initialize
cls
call C:\Sonar\sonarqube-4.1.1\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
echo Sonar is started.
echo[
pause
echo %date% >> C:\initiallog.txt
goto :test
cls



:test
   cls
   cd /d D:\PROJECT_Workspace\GUI
   call C:\Sonar\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.3\bin\sonar-runner.bat
   echo Sonar test is started...
   echo %date% >>C:\testlog.txt
   echo[
   pause 
   goto :menu

   :print
   cls
   type C:\testlog.txt
   type C:\initiallog.txt
   echo[
   pause
   goto :menu
```

This should do the trick! If there are any errors or concerns please let me know!